# Overflow scrollbars in tables in edge dont display correctly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I couldnt find this anywhere, so here we go. Tables with a max-width and overflow set to auto get a scrollbar like one would expect. This works great in Chrome, but Edge (and IE) seem to have a problem with these scrollbars

These pictures might help understand the problem im facing:

Chrome: (how i want it)

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwTMa.png)

Edge: (bad)

[edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53JeV.png)

(cant post pictures yet, need 10 reputation)

```html
<html>
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>tset</td>
            <td>tset test test testsetsetstsetsetsetststsetststsetst</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>tset</td>
            <td>tset test test testsetsetstsetsetsetststsetststsetst</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
```

```html
<html>
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
    td {
        overflow: auto;
        max-width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>tset</td>
            <td>tset test test testsetsetstsetsetsetststsetststsetst</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```